# Using variables in wildcard match for Blue Prism?

Tags: wildcard, blueprism

I'm trying to identify an element, using "Wildcard" as match type. Say, you click on an element, like a box, on a web page. You'd want that box to contain the word city. In that case, within application modeler, you'd to this:

```
*city*
```

This works fine. Now, what I want is to keep city as a variable, to make it more scalable. As an example, I'd create a data item named [city], and give it the value "Istanbul". So, when I do the same Wildcard match, with something like this:

```
*[city]*
```

, so I'd want Blue Prism to replace [city] with "Istanbul", and do a search that contains a box with Istanbul in it. Is this possible?

Comment: Great question, but to my knowledge functionality like this isn't supported in Blue Prism just yet.

Comment: I thought so at first, but Jerry's answer below proves that it can be done.

Answer (score 12):

You do it with dynamic match. In the application modeller, it will look something like:

[image]

Then in the stage you need to spy the element, edit the parameters and use the wild card match method with some string concatenation. I'll use a wait stage as example:

[image]

Comment: Dynamic attribute match works with wildcards (`*`)? Huh, TIL.

Comment: @esqew It's not only dynamic, it's dynamic and wild card match combined. It wouldn't work if in the stage I used the 'Equal' Match Type, so thankfully, it's flexible there too :)